# JPA ManyToMany relation with Composite key returns null for the IDs

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have a relationship between 2 entities with a ManyToMany relation and a composite key. You can see the code below.
The problem is, that I get the problem, that the entities Driver and Organization get null for their IDs and I think the problem is something with my JPA annotations for the relation between the classes.

Maybe I did something wrong with the JPA annotations?

```
@Embeddable
public class EmploymentKey implements IEmploymentKey, Serializable {

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Driver.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
   private IDriver driver;

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Organization.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")
   private IOrganization organization;

}
```

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "employmentKey.driver",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "employmentKey.organization",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")) })
public class Employment implements IEmployment {

         @EmbeddedId
         private EmploymentKey employmentKey = new EmploymentKey();
         private Date since;
         private boolean isActive;
    }
```

```
@Entity
public class Driver extends PlatformUser implements IDriver {

            @OneToMany(targetEntity = Employment.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employmentKey.driver")
            private Collection<IEmployment> employments = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

```
@Entity
public class Organization implements IOrganization {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Employment.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employmentKey.organization")
        private Collection<IEmployment> employments = new ArrayList<>();    
}
```

Comment: You can try switching `GenerationType.AUTO` to `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. AUTO doesn't always pick the best strategy.

Comment: Already tried that. Sadly driver and organization entities still have null in id

Comment: What about your database? Does your id have a sequence with which to auto increment?